# Cannot upgrade Ubuntu One subscription to 45GB

Tags: ubuntu-one, upgrade

I have two accounts. One is under email address A and I cannot update the subscription from 25GB to 45GB. The other account is under email address B for free 5GB and I wish to cancel that account. My Ubuntu One under A is full and will not allow me to add more files or upgrade. I believe the upgrade is being rejected by my bank with a country block that I have corrected, but still unable to upgrade my subscription. Please advise as soon as possible as I don't want to loose my backups.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this you'll need to contact Ubuntu One support and give us the email addresses for both accounts. You can do this at https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact